# buffering calculations in haskell array initialization

Tags: haskell

Right now i am porting my mathematical solution from c# to Haskell, learning Haskell in process. I have following code for Thompson algorithm:

```
xi[N] = a[N] / c[N];
eta[N] = f[N] / c[N];
for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    var cbxip = (c[i] - b[i] * xi[i + 1]);
    xi[i] = a[i] / cbxip;
    eta[i] = (f[i] + b[i] * eta[i + 1]) / cbxip;
}
{
    int i = 0;
    var cbxip = (c[i] - b[i] * xi[i + 1]);
    eta[i] = (f[i] + b[i] * eta[i + 1]) / cbxip;
}
```

How do I do it in Haskell?
I found info on array initialization, but I have several problems with it.

Say, I wrote the following code:

```
xi = [a[i] / (c[i] - b[i] * xi[i + 1]) | i <- 1..N-1] ++ [a[N] / c[N]]
etha = [(f[i] + b[i] * etha[i + 1] / (c[i] - b[i] * xi[i + 1]) | i <- 0..N-1] ++ [f[N] / c[N]]
```

The problems are following:

1. How do I specify I have to initialize array starting right? Do I even need to do so, or Haskell will grasp it by itself? If latter, how can it do that? isn't it is just a blackbox like`[f(i)|i<-[a..b]]` for a compiler?
2. (most problematic) For all `i` in `[1..N-1]` the part `(c[i] - b[i] * xi[i + 1])` is going to be evaluated twice. How can I fix this? Prior mapping it to some other array will cost memory and is impossible as I don't have `xi` array yet. 
   I thought of something like simultaneous mapping, but I am confused with how to apply it to array initializing.

Comment: Mark H has a good answer - you have to think  in lists and recursion, not arrays and loops. However to touch briefly on your two problems:

1) Haskell does lists rather than arrays, so you don't pre-initialise them, just build it as you go. Also, a list comprehension isn't a 'black box' to the compiler, it's actually just a syntactic shorthand for a recursive function over one or more existing lists, producing a list as a result.

2) the compiler may be able to spot this with pure expressions and optimise automatically, but to avoid repeating such code use `let...in` or `where` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably avoid using list comprehensions until you become really familiar with solving problems through recursion. Haskell is very different to C# in that you don't have "arrays" as such, which can be randomly accessed and inserted - you can't pre-allocate this space up front, because allocation is a side effect. Instead, consider everything to be linked lists, and to use recursion to iterate through them.

If we start with a top-down approach, we have a bunch of lists of numbers, and we need a function to iterate through them. If we passed these separately we would end up with a function signature like `[n] -> [n] -> [n] -> [n] -> [n] -> ..`. This is probably not a good idea considering they all seem to be the same size, N. Instead, we can use a tuple (or pair of tuples) to contain them, eg.

```
thompson :: Num n => [(n, n, n, n, n, n)] -> [(n, n)]
thompson [] = [] -- pattern to terminate recursion for empty lists

-- these variables are equivalent to your a[i], etc in C#
thompson ((a, b, c, f, xi, eta):_) = ?
```

If we are duplicating your C# exactly, we probably want patterns for the case of 2 elements in the list, since it seems that each iteration needs to access the current and next elements. For 2 or more elements.

```
-- handle final 2 elements
thompson ((a, _, c, f, xi, eta):[]) = ((a / c), (f / c))
thompson ((a0, b0, c0, f0, xi0, eta0):(_,_,_,_,xi1,eta1):[]) = ?
-- handle the regular case.
thompson ((a0, b0, c0, f0, xi0, eta0):(a1,b1,c1,f1,xi1,eta1):tail) = ?
```

Once you have the overall iterative structure, it should become more obvious how to implement what's in the loop. The loop is basically a function which takes one of these tuples, plus a tuple for the next xi/eta and does some calculation, returning a new tuple for xi/eta (or in the final case, just eta).  The a,b,c,f appear to not change.

```
doCalc1 :: Num n => (n, n, n, n, n, n) -> (n, n) -> (n, n)
doCalc1 (a, b, c, f, xi0, eta0) (xi1, eta1) = (a / cbxip, f + b * eta1 / cbxip)
  where cbxip = c - b * xi1

doCalc2 :: Num n => Num n => (n, n, n, n, n, n) -> (n, n) -> n
doCalc2 (a, b, c, f, xi0, eta0) (xi1, eta1) = f + b * eta1 / cbxip
  where cbxip = c - b * xi1
```

Now we just need to update thompson to call doCalc1/doCalc2, and recursively call itself with the tail.

```
thompson (head:next@(_,_,_,_,xi,eta):[])
    = (xi, doCalc2 head (xi, eta)) : thompson [next]
thompson (head:next@(_,_,_,_,xi,eta):tail) 
    = doCalc1 head (xi, eta) : thompson (next:tail)
```

Comment: hm, changing output type from ([d].[d]) to [(d.d)] really seems to be good idea. hovewer, i was not aware of the fact that list comprehensions return type is implemented as a linked list. I am okay working with those lists as with immutable types, but O(n) random access inside (N^4 + nested iterations) loop (i'm doing multidimensional parabolic equation with nonlinear coefficients, some of which are determined by another multidimensional elliptic equation) seems to be bad. Just came across Repa package, will look it through. Vectors from it seem to be quite fast.

Comment: @Mark One issue about your code: equations are tried in order, so you need to put the one that tests for exactly two elements *before* the general case, or else the general case catches all lists with at least two elements and the second case is ignored.